# Returning type casted array to main function

Tags: c, arrays, argument-passing

I am calling foo() function from main file whose return type is char*. from foo() I am returning int array by typecasting "(char*)ar". ar is array of size 2. 
Now I can retreive ar[0] in main() not ar[1](gives special char).

foo.c

```
#include <string.h>
int ar[2];
    char *foo(char* buf)
    {
        //static ar[2]  this also gives same problem

       //various task not concen with ar[]


    buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\0';
    if( (bytecount=send(hsock, buffer, strlen(buffer)-1,0))== -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }
    if((bytecount = recv(hsock, ar, 2 * sizeof(int), 0))== -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d\n", errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }

    printf("Positive count: %d \nNegative count: %d \n",ar[0],ar[1]); //This prints correct values
    close(hsock);

FINISH:
;
printf("array item2 %d \n",ar[1]); // Gives correct value for ar[0] and ar[1]
return (char *)ar;
}

main.cpp
```

here in below file ch[0] gives correct values while ch[1] gives special character

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "foo.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char buffer[1024];
    char *ch;
    strcpy(buffer,argv[1]);
    printf("Client : \n");
    if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
    {
              printf( "\n%s filename\n", argv[0] );
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("\nstring is :%s \n",buffer);
    ch=foo(buffer);
    printf("Counts :%d \n",(int)ch[1]);  //Here (int)ch[0] and ch[1] special char
    return (int)ch;
    }

}
```

What's wrong with ar[1], why it does not get received correctly?

Comment: you're going to get yelled at for undefined behavior and stuff.  You can't safely throw ints in a char* because of architectural limitations of where different types need to be aligned.

Comment: @xaxxon: SO I could not send int arra to main.cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a character then converting it to an int so you're only seeing the first 8 bytes.  You need to convert to an int* first (but this is not a good thing to do H2CO3 will tell you why most likely)

```
printf("Counts :%d \n",((int*)ch)[1];
```

Comment: This also gives same result as previous.

Comment: Thanks man, it works fantastic. I made mistake in previous comment!

Answer (score 1):

ch[1] is the second element of an array of chars, since the dimension of a char is (possibly) different from the dimension of an int you are not getting the second int.

You should return an int* or, at least, convert the char* to an int* in the main

```
int* i = (int*)ch;
i[0]; //instead of ch[0]
i[1]; //instead of ch[1]
```